How to fix cygwin with jpeg support to make it run?
I run cygwin with jpeg support on windows 10.
I copied
{mypath}\cygwin64\usr\share\doc\libjpeg-turbo\example.c

to a local folder and ran in that local folder
{mypath}\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe example.c -o example

This returned me:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x42a): undefined reference to `tj3GetScalingFactors'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x449): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xc5c): undefined reference to `tj3Init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xc73): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xe1b): undefined reference to `tj3Alloc'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xf2e): undefined reference to `tj3Transform'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xf3e): undefined reference to `tj3Free'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xf4a): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xf80): undefined reference to `tj3Free'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xfaa): undefined reference to `tj3Set'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xfba): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0xffe): undefined reference to `tj3Set'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x100e): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x104f): undefined reference to `tj3DecompressHeader'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x105f): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x109a): undefined reference to `tj3Get'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x10ae): undefined reference to `tj3Get'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x10c2): undefined reference to `tj3Get'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x10d6): undefined reference to `tj3Get'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x10ea): undefined reference to `tj3Get'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x1294): undefined reference to `tj3SetScalingFactor'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x12a4): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x13c2): undefined reference to `tj3Decompress8'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x13d2): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x1408): undefined reference to `tj3Free'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x144b): undefined reference to `tj3LoadImage8'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x1468): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x1583): undefined reference to `tj3Set'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x1593): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x15d7): undefined reference to `tj3Set'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x15e7): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x162b): undefined reference to `tj3Set'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x163b): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x16a7): undefined reference to `tj3Compress8'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x16b7): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x17f2): undefined reference to `tj3SaveImage8'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x1802): undefined reference to `tj3GetErrorStr'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x183c): undefined reference to `tj3Free'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x1848): undefined reference to `tj3Destroy'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/13/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/tyro/AppData/Local/Temp/ccNsD0bb.o:tjexample.c:(.text+0x1854): undefined reference to `tj3Free'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Since I did cygwin's setup-x86_64.exe several times now I assume its all updates to most recent version.
Also I made sure by running the setup-x86_64.exe to have those packages installed:
jpeg
libjpeg-devel
libjpeg-turbo-debuginfo
libjpeg8
libturbojpeg-devel
libturbojpeg0
all in version 3.0.4-1
How do come to a state where that example.c compiles without errors?

Failure to link against appropriate libraries/object files or compile implementation files

@MikeKingham based on your input I changed my compile-batch to  {mypath}\cygwin64\bin\gcc.exe example.c -o example -ljpeg ...which worked beautyfully - thanks man - yesterday I puzzled hours over hours with that and you helped in a few minutes
